# jQuery infinite scroll ignore browser bounce up

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this function that is loading 5 items at time based on the page number.  But what's happening is that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the $.post function fires once, and then again when the browser bounce finishes, because `position_bot == $(document).height()` is actually true twice.  Then 10 items are loaded each time.

I'm trying to find a way to ignore the browser bounce situation so the call only fires once.
Any suggestions or help would be great.

```
$(function(){
    $('#loading').show();
    var page = 1,
        total_brands = '<?php echo $brandsCount?>',
        post_link = '<?php echo $brandsUrl?>',
        post_data = {page_num: page};

    $.post(post_link, post_data, function(data){
        $('.brandsResult').append(data);
        $('#loading').hide();
    });

    $(window).scroll(function (e) {

        var position_bot = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
            displayed_brands = $('ul.category-list > li').length;               

        // Show loading image if near bottom
        if(position_bot > $(document).height() - 120 && displayed_brands < total_brands) {
            $('#loading').show();
        }

        // If page is at the bottom
        if(position_bot == $(document).height()) {

            // Increase page number
            page++;
            post_data = { page_num: page };
            console.log('page', page);

            // Check if all items are displayed
            if((page-1) * 5 > total_brands){
                $('#loading').hide();
            } else {    
            // Firing twice ???
                $.post(post_link, post_data, function(data){
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('.brandsResult').append(data);
                });

            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set a boolean to control loading state and tell the code not to do anything if true...

```
    var processing = false;

if(position_bot == $(document).height() && !processing) {

    if((page-1) * 5 > total_brands){
       $('#loading').hide();
       processing = false;
    } else {    
       processing = true;
       $.post(post_link, post_data, function(data){
           $('#loading').hide();
           $('.brandsResult').append(data);
           processing = false;
       });

    }
}
```

I believe this is happening cause $('#loading').show() is pushing the screen, acting as a change in height, which is not enough to push beyond the boundaries of your conditional. A simple boolean would (or could) prevent this. It may require some adjustments and this is just a basic and totally untested example.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works.  And it's also great that you pointed out that showing the loader might actually be an issue too, but it just seemed like the the browser bounce came back up, it triggered another call.

Comment: alternatively you could try position absolute, z-index for the loading element. If it is absolute and center screen, for example, it won't push the screen. That of course depends on your design.